# How to decrease DC Voltage and Increase Current

Tags: voltage-regulator, step-down

I am using a buck converter to reduce source DC 12 V 1 A to 5 V. It does reduces the voltage but the problem is that it also reduces current i.e; less than 1 A. I want to keep the POWER same at all voltage levels i.e; 12 W in this case. Why power is not same after conversion? And how it can be done?

Comment: Which buck converter are you using? Please share the datasheet and schematic.

Comment: Also, realistically, you're always going to get less power at the output, since no converter can truly conserve energy.

Comment: LM2596HV . Here is the link to this module https://digilog.pk/products/adjustable-dc-buck-converter-lm2596hv-in-pakistan?_pos=5&_sid=ccd76ef79&_ss=r

Comment: Please share the schematic of your design.

Comment: It's always the same [counterfeit LM2596 modules](https://k6jca.blogspot.com/2018/02/counterfeit-lm2596-regulator-boards.html)

Comment: How do you know your *buck converter also reduces current i.e; less than 1 A*?

Comment: A buck converter increases current because the current at the output of a buck converter is greater than the current at the input. This has nothing to do with how much the current would've been if you didn't have the converter.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing the schematic, it sounds like you may have a resistive load on the output of your converter:

V=IR -> V/I = R

eg. 5V / <1A = <5Ω

I have to *assume* you expected to see 2.4A of load current.

P =VI -> P/V = I

eg. 12W / 5V  = 2.4A

To answer your first question:

Unless your load has a dynamic circuit where it draws more current when there is a reduction in voltage, you will typically have reduced current draw as the voltage provided to your circuit is reduced.
If your load is not dynamic, are you satisfying the voltage required to power your circuit? Are components not turning on because they require > 5V Vcc etc.?

To try answer your second question as you have not acknowledged the commenters requests for providing a schematic:

*IF* you have a purely resistive load that you are trying to heat up (a filament or heater?), try implementing a constant current sink in series between your buck converter and load.

Answer (score 0):

The load sets the current, not the source. If you see lower current it's because your particular load is not asking for it (at that voltage). Don't blame the converter.